# how to access the specific contextual menu according to name of menu by AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

Is it possible to click the specific contextual menu in an application in macOS by using AppleScript?

e.g. in Chrome , I want to click "copy picture address"，but I don't want to do the whole process manually every time when I want to get the address of a picture.

So is it possible to access the contextual menu by name by AppleScript automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: If you happen to use the opensource key-mapper "Karabiner Elements" it is really simple. . . . Problem with AppleScript is to click JUST where your cursor is. In K-E you simply call "button2" ("condition" the action to Chrome) then do a "to_delayed_action" (just like "delay 0.3" in AS), "key_code": "c" [or other starting letter of menu item / arrow keys to navigate] and: DONE. . . . The fantastic "extra" of K-E is: you AUTOMATICALLY get a shortcut installed. I use a simple "shift"-shortcut in Safari to context menu "Element-Informationen" (German system) as I never use "shift" in Safari …

Answer (score -1):

If you break your problem down, you'll see that there's no solution more efficient than the current method you're using. Let's count the manoeuvres involved in using a scripting solution:

1. any script that accesses a contextual menu needs to know the image to which the contextual menu relates, either by mouse-click or keyboard shortcut;
2. any script you run needs to be triggered, either by accessing it from a menu bar (multiple mouse clicks) or pressing a hotkey.

These two things have already equalled or exceeded the number of manoeuvres it normally takes by accessing the contextual menu manually, namely: *right-click* + *single-click* = 2 manoeuvres.

***If***, on the other hand, you're looking to automate a process by which you can retrieve the link to *every* image on a web page, that's something that can be done with JavaScript with massive efficiency savings:

```
    Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('img'),x=>x.src)
```

To incorporate this into an AppleScript, you need to enable an option to allow JavaScript to automate the *Chrome* browser.  To do this (I'm using *Chrome* version 69), select from the menu *View > Developer > Allow JavaScript From Apple Events* and make sure it is ticked.

Then test this AppleScript code, which should return a list of image sources from whichever page is currently displayed in *Google Chrome*:

```
    tell application "Google Chrome" to tell ¬
        the front window to tell ¬
        the active tab to execute javascript ¬
        "Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('img'),x=>x.src)"
```

Comment: -1 User 4004 in his question definitely asks for a way to "get the address of a picture", so obviously a  script that "collects" all pictures' addresses is NOT what he is seeking. . . . If you dare to look beyond AppleScript's constrictions (which he, though, favours) there is an easier solution by employing  "Karabiner Elements" which in such cases is an ideal supplement to AS (as described in my comment to the original question).

Comment: @clemsamlang You’re quoting the OP out of context, as he actually said “every time when I want to get the address of a picture”, which doesn’t imply he only wishes to get the link for one specific picture.  Although it also doesn’t imply he wants to get the links for all pictures, I don’t see the harm in providing that option to him, given that I did it in a way that clearly stated that this was an alternative interpretation of his needs.  A bit harsh to downvote for that reason, but thank you for explaining your reasons.  I think _Karabiner_ is a good idea.

Comment: I am NOT quoting the OP out of context, as you falsely try to make a simple "every time when I want" –consisting of a row of singular "wants" on singular pages, at least of individually "selected" pictures– into a "EVERY picture no matter if I WANT it". This results in a list of pictures that MUST be searched in a 2nd step and/or evaluated, making your solution rather cumbersome. . . Whereas MINE provides a "ONE–manoeuvre" way to his goal! . . You may not know Karabiner Elements well, otherwise you'd be aware that it allows a user to "shortcut-click" on any item where his cursor hovers…

Comment: @clemsamlang I'm not sure if you misread me, but I said that I think _Karabiner_ is a good idea.  That is to say, I was being supportive of your idea.  Let's try and keep this fun, _civil_, and cooperative.  And don't forget, problems can and do have more than one solution, each with their benefits and drawbacks.  But I like your _Karabiner_ solution.

Comment: I admit to have down voted your answer (that may be helpful to others than the current OP) from some anger at other users here, who down voted some of my "pragmatic" and fully working solutions (from OPs' view!) because I didn't admire their solutions that use AppleScripObj or some other "higher language". I can't delete my down-vote unless you change your answer. Apologies.

Comment: @clemsamlang So you're saying that you down voted my answer here because you're angry that _other_ users have down voted your answers elsewhere ?  But that you can't rescind your down-vote ?  Not only is that not how down voting is supposed to work, but that seems very unfriendly.  But it's up to you, I'm not going to press the matter.  I understand how disheartening down votes are, but please try not to take your frustrations out on other people's answers like that.  If your downvote now made me angry and I went and down voted someone else, it would just create more and more angry downvotes.

Comment: So now you are SOO angry with me because I was angry with other users (I am not absolutely sure that you weren't among them ;-) ) that you didn't GET my hint that you should make a minor edit and I will undo my down vote? How about simply MAKING that tiny edit and getting back your point … I don't feel like explaining to you how I FIND other users' behaviour here. But as YOU started this VERY off-topic dialog with me I'll just let you know that I find it hideous of others to downvote without giving reasons (except when facts are obvious) …

Comment: I’m not angry @clemsamlang and I’m happy you explained yourself.  I’m disappointed you chose to take your anger out on me, but that’s your decision, but I choose not to be coerced into changing a perfectly good answer just because you demand that I should.  But I think we should move past this, what’s done is done.  Lets put this to rest now and look towards a more cooperative and civil interaction in the future. Don’t forget, this site should be a community, and it should be friendly, and educational, and above all, fun.  So let’s be part of that.

Comment: That's okay with me, but just let me remind you that the OP explicitly asked to get information on `A(!) picture` NOT on `every(!) picture` and that he asked for a one-click-solution which I can offer him, while you unwittingly denied the possibility AND necessity to him. Normally I would just have corrected your opinion but not have it down voted.

Answer (score -1):

This code requires the [“Cliclick” is short for “Command-Line Interface Click”. It is a a tiny shell/Terminal application that will emulate mouse clicks or series of mouse clicks (including doubleclicks and control-clicks) at arbitrary screen coordinates. Moreover, it lets you move the mouse, get the current mouse coordinates, press modifier keys etc.](https://www.bluem.net/en/projects/cliclick/), Which is free for download and easy to install.

If you create a new service in Automator and paste this following code into a “Run AppleScript” command into your Automator workflow, you can then create a keyboard shortcut in system preferences which will launch the service.  Using Google Chrome with your mouse cursor hovered over any image… just press your shortcut keys that you defined and it will copy the image address to your clipboard

---

On my system I have. cliclick in the following directory: /usr/local/bin/cliclick.  Because of this location, in my AppleScript code and in Terminal app, I need to use the full path to cliclick to call the command. For example: `do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick  rc:."` In AppleScript is telling cliclick to right-click.

```
property theApp : "Google Chrome"
property menuItemName : "Copy Image Address"
property menuItemName2 : "Copy Link Address"
property mouseLocation : missing value
property menuItems : missing value

run firstTry

script firstTry
    tell application theApp to activate
    repeat while application theApp is not running
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    tell application "System Events" to tell its application process theApp ¬
        to tell its attribute "AXEnhancedUserInterface"
        set value to true
    end tell
    delay 0.1
    set mouseLocation to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick  p"
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick  rc:."
    delay 0.1
    tell application "System Events" to tell its application process theApp to tell its window 1 ¬
        to tell its scroll area 1 to tell its menu 1
        delay 0.1
        set menuItems to its name of menu items
        set menuItems to text of menuItems
        try
            click menu item menuItemName
        on error errMsg number errNum
            try
                click menu item menuItemName2
            on error errMsg number errNum
                key code 53 -- press esc key
                run my secondTry
            end try
        end try
    end tell
end script

script secondTry
    tell application theApp to activate
    repeat while application theApp is not running
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    tell application "System Events" to tell its application process theApp ¬
        to tell its attribute "AXEnhancedUserInterface"
        set value to true
    end tell
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick  m:" & mouseLocation
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick  rc:."
    delay 0.3
    activate
    tell application theApp
        activate
        set theChoice to (choose from list menuItems ¬
            with title ¬
            "Choose A Link" with prompt ¬
            "Choose A Link" OK button name ¬
            "Click Menu Item" cancel button name "Cancel") as string
    end tell
    delay 0.1
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick  m:" & mouseLocation
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick  rc:."
    tell application "System Events" to tell its application process theApp to tell its window 1 ¬
        to tell its scroll area 1 to tell its menu 1
        delay 0.1
        try
            click menu item theChoice
        on error errMsg number errNum
            try
                click menu item theChoice
            on error errMsg number errNum
                key code 53 -- press esc key
            end try
        end try
    end tell
end script
```

---

Here is an example using the keyboard shortcut after I created the Automator service. In this example my mouse is hovered directly over an image.  It copies the image address and in a new browser window I paste the image address and go to its URL.

[image]

---

This the second example shows what happens if I call the keyboard shortcut with my mouse not above an image

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for help. \n
But when I run the script, it gives "Scripting Error": 
Error Number: -1719
System Events got an error: Can’t get scroll area 1 of window 1 of application process "Google Chrome". Invalid index.

Comment: @user4004  Since AppleScript no longer allows the usage of third-party scripting additions, the new updated AppleScript code utilizes the cliclick shell application instead of the previous AppleScript toolbox scripting addition..  Give it a shot and let me know if you stumble across any problems

Comment: This solution looks like quite some over-kill to me. Just use the 3rd party key-remapper Karabiner-Elements as described in comments on original question: simple and an ideal supplement to AppleScript's constrictions …